# Setting headers in POST request with Java

Tags: java, http, post

I use Robotium to test Android app. In the middle of a test I need to create POST request to server to some money to user and then verify that changes are reflected in UI.

Request looks like:

> wwww.testserver.com/userAddMoney?user_id=1&amount=999

But to authorize on server I need to pass special parameters to Header of request:

> Headers: X-Testing-Auth-Secret: kI7wGju76kjhJHGklk76

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could look into the [Apache HC](http://hc.apache.org/) package:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost( "http://wwww.testserver.com/userAddMoney" );
...
post.addHeader( "X-Testing-Auth-Secret" , "kI7wGju76kjhJHGklk76" );
...
```

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation